# How to make a BrowseFragment with only one row visible

Tags: android, android-tv

How can I make an Android TV BrowseFragment interface with only one row visible like the YouTube app?

[image: screenshot1]

This is the basic structure of my code:

```java
BrowseFragment browseFragment = BrowseFragment.getInstance();

browseFragment.setHeadersState(BrowseFragment.HEADERS_ENABLED);
browseFragment.setTitle(getString(R.string.AplicationName));
browseFragment.setBadgeDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.badge));

ArrayObjectAdapter rowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());


for ( int i = 0; i < itemsCount; ++i ) {

    HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(i, "Header" + items[i].title);
    ArrayObjectAdapter rowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new CardPresenter());

    for ( int i = 0; i < subitemsCount; ++i ) {
        rowAdapter.add(subitems[i]);
    }

    rowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, rowAdapter));


}

browseFragment.setAdapter(rowsAdapter);
```

This generates all the headers on the left but instead of one single visible row of items, I get a grid with all the rows like the sample app:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: You will find that the BrowseFragment class (included on leanback library) have commented tips and instructions on how to customize yours HeadersFragment and RowsFragment. You will have to extend the MainFragmentAdapterRegistry class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **customized BrowseFragment component** offered here: https://github.com/dextorer/BuildingForAndroidTV

You will be able to replicate the same UI structure that the YouTube app for TV is offering.

---

**UPDATE**

I've written up a simple library that extends Leanback and offers a more streamlined (and reliable) customization. Here it is:

[Sofa](https://github.com/dextorer/Sofa)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609475/vertical-list-like-android-phones-in-android-tv-leanback, How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

What I did was extend the ListRowPresenter class (ex: ListVideosRowPresenter), and add this code:

```
@Override
protected void onSelectLevelChanged(RowPresenter.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onSelectLevelChanged(holder);

    if (vh.isSelected()){
        vh.getGridView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        vh.getGridView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Then, on the MainFragment Class, when you create the adapters (HeadersAdapters, and RowsAdapters) you have to use your extended class:

```
mHeadersAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListVideosRowPresenter());
```

and to avoid showing headers, (on the rowsFragment) I had to create two separated adapters (one for HeadersFragment and other for RowsFragment):

```
        HeaderItem categoryHeader = new HeaderItem(i, MovieList.MOVIE_CATEGORY[i]);
        CustomListRow headersRow = new CustomListRow(categoryHeader, listRowAdapter);
        //I pass null as the header, so no header will be displayed on the RowsFragment
        CustomListRow listRow = new CustomListRow(null, listRowAdapter, MovieList.MOVIE_CATEGORY[i]);
        mRowsAdapter.add(listRow);
        mHeadersAdapter.add(headersRow);
```

and finally write a new setAdapter method (with two parameters)on the MainFragment:

```
public void setAdapter(ObjectAdapter adapterHeaders, ObjectAdapter adapterRows) {
    //this line sets the same adapter for both fragments (headers and rows)
    setAdapter(adapterRows);
    //this line sets the adapter for the HeadersFragment only
    getHeadersFragment().setAdapter(adapterHeaders);
}
```

Comment: I want to try your method, but isn't the ListRowPresenter class in the Leanback library? How did you extend the class? Did you have to decompile, edit and the recompile again?

Comment: Hi. I wrote this answer several years ago. In that time you (as a programmer) were able to extend that classes, also to check the code. (just stand over them and press ctrl + click )  Best wishes

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! I can check the code of ListRowPresenter, but I can't edit it as it's locked. I only started android development a few days ago so I really don't understand how to extend a class of Leanback. Do you open a new java file? If yes, where should I put this file? In the original Leanback library?

Comment: ok, you have to write a new class that extends  "ListRowPresenter" and override the methods (just the listed in the answer above) . If you have questions about how to extend a class, just check on the internet there is a lot of examles. Then follow with the other steps listed above. De nada amigo!

Comment: @SebastianCorradi , can you help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67883215/4732846 Thanks.