# Vertical list like android phones in android tv leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to create a simple vertical list (single column in a row), which is only scrollable vertically not horizontally. How do i achieve this on android tv using leanback ?

Refer below image for more clarification on ui requirement.

I tried using VerticalSupportFragment, but a row item doesn't spans to a full width, tried changing styles and presenter also.

Thanks in advance, is there any way to achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Did you achieve it? I'm having a lot of trouble trying to fill every item horizontally

Answer (score 4):

If you use a `VerticalGridSupportFragment` you can set the number of columns like this:

```java
VerticalGridPresenter presenter = new VerticalGridPresenter();
gridPresenter.setNumberOfColumns(1);
setGridPresenter(gridPresenter);
```

This effectively gives you a vertical list. Then you can edit the width of the view in your row item presenter. For example if you want the view to fill the screen horizontally you could do something like:

```java
int height = 42;
int width = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Comment: You can add a header for the entire grid, but if you want headers for the individual rows you'll probably have to build it into the row item. You should check out `RowsSupportFragment`, it is probably closer to what you want.