# How to create vertical list like the settings screen for android tv

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I want to create a simple one-columned **vertical** list like the list on the Settings App on Android tv (Check attached image). How do I achieve this on android tv using leanback?

I've tried using a regular Recyclerview like on an android phone and I didn't get the same feel even after implementing OnFocusChangeListener.

Someone suggested VerticalSupportFragment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609475/vertical-list-like-android-phones-in-android-tv-leanback) but other people mentioned there were bugs getting it to reach the full width

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

[image: Settings Page]

Answer (score -1):

Use `androidx.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView`

```
val adapter = MyAdapter()
 adapter.setItems(list)
 verticalGridView.adapter = adapter
```