# How to customise fragment with row transitions like we have in VideoSupportFragment of android leanback component?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to build a fragment with overlay transition like we get in VideoSupportFragment of leanback. The playback row and the bottom row tray. Without using the VideoSupportFragment. I mean I don't have use case to play the video, but just to have that kind of overlay transition on top of some background.

[image]

[image]

Edit : I am referring to scrolling behaviour of playback control row and related videos row.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is basically a `VerticalGridView` with a `PlaybackRow` and a `ListRow`

I would build a new custom class using parts of the code in `PlaybackSupportFragment` which already has those implemented.

[Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/leanback/src/main/java/androidx/leanback/app/PlaybackSupportFragment.java)

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/leanback/app/PlaybackSupportFragment)

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by overlay transition. Do you mean the automatic scrolling between the rows or the opening/closing of the overlays? If you mean the automatic scrolling, it is handled by the VerticalGridView. You can create a single column VerticalGridView with two custom rows (or use the PlaybackRow and ListRow as in PlaybackSupportFragment).

Comment: Yes, I was referring the auto scrolling of playback rows and the related videos row. But for me playback row is replaced by the button. VerticalGridView is it ? ,  Will give a try, if you could share any reference, it would be great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm getting it right, but for this:

*"I was referring the auto scrolling of playback rows and the related videos row."*
You should listen to an "onCompleteEvent" and then move to ne netx video, and play it

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant, I want to achieve the transition of playback control row and the related video row. Initially only the playback control is shown and as you move down it scrolls up and related videos row is shown.